# Python function deletes my var?

Tags: python, function, variables

I have the following code:

```
def moveServo(x, y):
    print x
    print y
    s1.ChangeDutyCycle(x)
    s2.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
    print "Successfull"
    print x
    print y

@app.route('/cameramove/', methods=['GET'])
def cameramove():
    ret_data = True

    x = request.args.get('x')
    y = request.args.get('y')
    moveServo(x, y)

    return jsonify(ret_data)
```

The output is:

```
192.168.178.23 - - [02/Aug/2016 19:36:24] "GET /cameramove/?x=7.8&y=9.3 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
7.8
9.4
192.168.178.23 - - [02/Aug/2016 19:36:24] "GET /cameramove/?x=7.8&y=9.4 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
7.8
9.4
```

You see that the function resets the variables. But when i change the definition of the var's:

```
def moveServo(x, y):
    print x
    print y
    s1.ChangeDutyCycle(x)
    s2.ChangeDutyCycle(y)
    print "Successfull"
    print x
    print y

@app.route('/cameramove/', methods=['GET'])
def cameramove():
    ret_data = True

    x = 5.6
    y = 3.9
    moveServo(x, y)

    return jsonify(ret_data)
```

The output:

```
192.168.178.23 - - [02/Aug/2016 19:40:44] "GET /cameramove/?x=6.8&y=9.1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
5.6
3.9
Successfull
5.6
3.9
```

Does it work at once :O

Can anybody help me? I have no idea why the function would not accept the variables.

Comment: A little more context may help here.. e.g. what is the decorator doing? what's in `request`?

Comment: your log suggests that the http status code is 500 which means "server error" and there is no "successful" in the first log - propably because `request.args.get('x')` returns a string which does not work as input for `ChangeDutyCycle` (just guessing). try replacing `request.args.get('x')` with `float(request.args.get('x'))`. (same for y)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
float(request.args.get('x'))
```